# XMPP Connection manager "Strophe.Connection" returns ATTACHED status instead of CONNECTED

Tags: jquery, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I use Strophe.Connection    to create and initialize a Strophe.Connection object and I start the connection process with 'connect' function but it return ATTACHED status instead of CONNECTED as expected in the book.

This code come from the Jack Moffitt 'Professional XMPP programming with JavaScript and JQuery" but it doesn't work for me :-(

- It's same with both Openfire and eJabberd server
- It's same when configuring Apach to proxy BOSH
- It's same with a test server at http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind
- BOSH status is ok when entering http://localhost:5280/http-bind or http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind

I've passed the all day on it and I'm getting big headache. Any help would be appreciate.
Thank you,

Here is the code :

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
        "http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
    conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        } 
    });
```

In order to understand what is going on I've modified the code as this (with the connect status):

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
        "http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
    conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.ERROR) {
            alert ('status ERROR');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
            alert ('status CONNECTING');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
            alert ('status CONNFAIL');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING) {
            alert ('status AUTHENTICATING');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL) {
            alert ('status AUTHFAIL');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.ATTACHED);
            alert ('status ATTACHED');
```

It show me two status : CONNECTING then ATTACHED. Why I can not have CONNECTED status as expected in the book ???

Comment: There is problem in your code, your last else if block is terminated so it would always execute alert ('status ATTACHED');

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to diagnose this. You might try running in Firefox or Chrome and viewing the network panel in the developer tools to see what error is actually occurring.

I imagine this is just a cross-domain request issue.

Comment: Thank for replying Jack. What is the network panel in the developper tools ? I've try with Firebug but I'm not expert in it and don't know how to track bug with this tool. (I've modified the post with the status I finnaly have : it is CONNECTING then ATTACHED. After the box is hidden and blank page).

Comment: I found the network pannel in Chrome but I don't see any error in it. Do you have any idea why the connection is "ATTACHED" instead of "CONNECTED" ? tx. Florent

Comment: Well, in fact the connection is not ATTACHED. Whatever the status I have in the last line (Strophe.Status.ATTACHED) it executs the alert ('status ATTACHED');

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get Strophe working with my Openfire server by adding a new rule in .htaccess that will redirect the request to http-bind.

```
RewriteRule http-bind/ http://www.mydomain.info:7070/http-bind/ [P]
```

The JS code:

```
var DEV = {};
var jq  = jQuery;
DEV.APP = {};
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://www.mydomain.info/http-bind/';
var connection = null;

function log(msg) 
{
    jq('body').append('<div></div>').append(document.createTextNode(msg));
}

function rawInput(data)
{
    log('RECV: ' + data);          
}

function rawOutput(data)
{
    log('SENT: ' + data);
}

function onConnect(status)
{
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
        log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
        log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
        log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
        log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        log('Strophe is connected.');
        // connection.disconnect();
    }
}

jq(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
    connection.rawInput = rawInput;
    connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;

    connection.connect("username", "password", onConnect);
});
```

As a note, the cross-domain policy if applied even if you try to access a resource what is on same domain but on different port.

Hope this helps.

Edit:
  My .htaccess looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule http-bind/ http://www.domain.info:7070/http-bind/ [P]
```

Comment: Hi Liviu, I have created the .htaccess file with the RewriteRule in the www directory but after Apache restart it detects error and does not allow me to connect. I reverse.

Comment: It is possible to have an error in your .htaccess. See a above my .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I go for "metajack"'s suggestion. I have never used chrome network panel, but in firefox, I find firebug quite handy. After you installed firebug, all you need to do is to "enable all panels". Under "Net" tab you have all the requests you send and receive. Under "Net", "All" tab is basically the place where firebug shows all the network activities. Now some where at the bottom of your list you must be able to see your http-bind requests (on my laptop I have BOSH setup on Apache and the Proxy is set as "http-bind"; the exact address depends on your setting). Expand your http-bind node, and select "Post" tab. There you will be able to see your HTTP Post request. Now, if you click on "Response" it shows you the response you have got from your XMPP server.
[Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleID=196802787&dept_url=/dept/debug/) is a tutorial by fire bug creator himself.